# Set-AzureDeployment ignores relative path

Tags: powershell, azure

```
PS C:\Users\dimon\src\panama\Panama> Set-AzureDeployment -Config -ServiceName pms-dimon -Slot "Production" -Configuration .\ServiceConfiguration.Test.cscfg -Verbose
Set-AzureDeployment : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\dimon\ServiceConfiguration.Test.cscfg'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureDeployment -Config -ServiceName pms-dimon -Slot "Production" -Configur ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureDeployment], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.SetAzureDeploymentCommand
```

Instead of looking for a `ServiceConfigiration.Test.cscfg` file in a current directory `Set-AzureDeployment` is expecting to find this file in the home directory of current user, which is frankly speaking pretty obnoxious.

Is there a some common Powershell pattern to run all cmdlet function starting from a home directory? Why?

Comment: Would the relative path be considered a pipeline value?  If that is so, the `-Configuration` switch does not accept pipeline values per the MSDN.

Comment: I would be curious how `-Configuration` deals with that string data. It accepts a string but it is attempting to translate it somehow. `Resolve-Path` could be a workaround but I'm curious about how the param is defined for `-Configuration` and its data validation.

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly pass the full path:

```
Set-AzureDeployment -Config -ServiceName pms-dimon -Slot "Production" `
  -Configuration $(rvpa .\ServiceConfiguration.Test.cscfg) -Verbose
```

And to answer your question: no, PowerShell does nothing special with home directories. However, the value of the current directory as exposed to non-PowerShell commands (`[Environment]::CurrentDirectory`) does not change if you do `cd`, which is often a source of surprises. If `Set-AzureDeployment` passes its argument to a non-PowerShell command, that would explain the behavior.

To resolve that in a general way, you can simply change the current directory to PowerShell's location before you issue further commands:

```
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $(pwd)
```

Obviously, this only works if the current location is in a file system, not any of the other exotic locations PowerShell supports.